# The fourth annual holiday bountapalooza

Tags: discussion, status-completed, bounty

The [last](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4186/627) [three](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5675/627) [years](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6958/627), we've had an unofficial holiday bountapalooza, which we run concurrently with [Winter Bash](https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/). It's about giving back to the community by placing bounties on questions that need answers, and setting bounties to reward preexisting amazing answers. We'll keep track of the bountied posts in a community wiki answer below this question.

Now, after [the events of this fall](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7512/627), I think very few of us are feeling at all jolly. I myself am not exactly eagerly participating in Winter Bash - I think I'll keep my normal black hat, if that's all right. But I do think we should once again do the bountapalooza, because it's a celebration of *each other*. Regardless of the actions Stack Overflow the company has taken, we the users of Worldbuilding have spent years building this site - its scope, its culture, and its community. We've done this largely on our own. And I think it's worth celebrating what *we* - the current *and* past  users of the site - have done to make the Internet a better place. I for one would like to honor those who have put so much work into building this world.

Let the bounties begin!

Comment: I also wanted to note that I have 80,000 reputation points. I quite frankly do not need them all and would like to see some go to folks who deserve them! Let me know if you know of a question you would like to see me bounty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## List of bountied questions

Add your latest bounty here!

- [Plausibility of helium dominated atmospheres on super-Earths](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/152426/627), asked by [TheDyingOfLight](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/58321/thedyingoflight) and bountied by [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868) (+200)
- [How soon can the first stars form?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/146090/627), asked by [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868) and bountied by [We are Monica.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/55743/we-are-monica) (+200)
- [Would tanks or small walkers be better for Lunar militaries?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/106757/627), asked and bountied by [skout](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/38174/skout) (+50)
- [Is it possible for a religion with >1 billion followers to die out?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/33806/is-it-possible-for-a-religion-with-1-billion-followers-to-die-out), asked by [Serban](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3510/serban-tanasa) bountied by [James](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james) (+100)
- [How do ballistic trajectories work in a rotating cylinder world?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/150259/30492) asked and bountied by [L.Dutch-reinstate-Monica](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/30492/l-dutch-reinstate-monica) (+100)
- [How to make FTL-technology an narratively interesting suicide-pact-technology?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/162649/627), asked by [TheDyingOfLight](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/58321/thedyingoflight) and bountied by [Megha](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/21689/megha) (+50)
- [Why might the ability to attack using directed nerve stimulation evolve?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/163584/627), asked by [Bryan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/45813/bryan) and bountied by [DT Cooper](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/52876/dt-cooper) (+50)
- [How to make an alien game show be fair when hosting many different species?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/121120/627), asked by [Enigma](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/54112/enigma) and bountied by [Bryan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/45813/bryan) (+300)
- [What would powers based of the strong force look like?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/163542/627), asked and bountied by [Seraphim](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/69795/seraphim) (+50)
- [How to make an alien game show be fair when hosting many different species?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/121120/627), asked by [Enigma](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/54112/enigma) and bountied by [DT Cooper](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/52876/dt-cooper) (+150)
- [Is it safe to orbit HDE 226868?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/71971/627), asked and bountied by [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868) (+100)
- [How do I determine the physical size of a quartz crystal of a given shape and vibrational mode needed to approximate a specific resonant frequency?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/163972/627), asked by [Shalvenay](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3097/shalvenay) and bountied by [SRM - Reinstate Monica](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/26246/srm-reinstate-monica) (+50)
- [Can you replace goethite with something else in limpet teeth to decrease its density and maintain its strength?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/160640/627), asked by [Mephistopheles](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/32097/mephistopheles) and bountied by [SRM - Reinstate Monica](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/26246/srm-reinstate-monica) (+50)
- [How can an individual provide a higher quality of energy the more depleted it becomes?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/164400/627), asked and bountied by [Incognito](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/52361/incognito) (+50)
- [Turning iron that is unusable by magic civilizations into an alloy usable by them](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/164460/627), asked and bountied by [Failus Maximus](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/67499/failus-maximus) (+100)

Here are our stats for this year's bountapalooza:

- 15 bounties started . . .
- on 14 different questions . . .
- by 12 different users . . .
- for a total of 1600 reputation points.

Happy holidays!